# Desktop Application to merge with Linux Site

Tags: linux, windows

I have a desktop Application, that is game. if user wants to use or can say play this game. He needs this to install on their system. Cool Enough !

Now i have a Linux site, mean to say a Linux Server. I want to add this application to my Linux server. Means users simply Navigate my Site's URL and play a game.

So i want to know , is my requirement is feasible or not? Hard to listen about no :(

Please guide me as per your best knowledge. I will admire yours opinions...

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Process.Start(Server.MapPath("APD Equity Calculator.exe"));
            }
```